Should i write minimal or big ones with data duplication in microservices
Consider i have these two models that live in a different microservices. I can write them in two ways:
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }       
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }   
    public int Quantity { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }  
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}
public class Delivery
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }    
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!; 
    public Guid WarehouseId { get; set; } = null!;
    public DeliveryStatus Status { get; set; }
}

In case we'd need particular order details from the DeliveryMicroservice, we'd query it from the OrderMicroservice using Rest or whatever(high coupling, sync queries). Or we can write them as follows
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }   
    public int Quantity { get; set; }   
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!; 
    public string WarehouseName { get; set; } = null!;
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DeliveryStatus DeliveryStatus {get;set;}
}
public class Delivery
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }    
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }   
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!; 
    public Guid WarehouseId { get; set; } = null!;
    public DeliveryStatus Status { get; set; }
}

Now we dont need to query anything from different microservices as each one of them contains all necessary information it needs to operate. If shared properties(like DeliveryStatus) change, microservice who did this publishes the OrderDeliveryDetailsChanges with the new DeliveryStatus and other microservices copy it(all happens asynchronously via broker).
The problems here that i see: probable data inconsistency in case published events can't be delivered and data duplication(we store WarehouseId in the delivery service and it's memory efficient, but in OrderService we store it's name and it's not efficient as warehouses are just a database dictionary entries)

It looks to me as though you are entangling two very different concerns (which might be the real problem, or might just means that your description of the actual problem is pulling in unrelated concerns).
The first reference to review is Data on the Outside Versus Data on the Inside (Pat Helland, 2005).  In particular, we want to think carefully about locked data (we're using logical constructs to prevent anyone else from changing the data while we are working on it) vs unlocked data (we're working from a stale copy of data, the authoritative copy may have changed since we made our copy).
If you are pulling data from another (micro)service, then normally that will be unlocked data (we're not going to block delivery processing from making progress because we are working on an order, right?).  With unlocked data, you are not normally concerned with where it comes from, but rather how old your copy is.
So any of "fetch an unlocked copy synchronously, or fail", "fetch an unlocked copy from an asynchronously updated cache, or fail", "fetch from cache, fall back to a synchronous call, or fail", "fetch with synchronous call, fall back to async cache, or fail" can be the "right" design, depending on how you value the different tradeoffs.
But that's a very different question from "how should we model this information in local memory".
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }   
    public int Quantity { get; set; }   
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!; 
    public string WarehouseName { get; set; } = null!;
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DeliveryStatus DeliveryStatus {get;set;}
}
public class Delivery
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }    
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }   
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!; 
    public Guid WarehouseId { get; set; } = null!;
    public DeliveryStatus Status { get; set; }
}

I find this design unsatisfactory because the values that we can change within a service are not obviously distinct from the values we can not change (because some other service has authority over that information).
Very roughly: order processing should not be tightly coupled to strategy we use to obtain the unlocked copy of delivery information; therefore we probably don't want code that implies that the (unlocked) delivery information is part of the dame data entity as the (locked) order information.
So if our order processing really does need an unlocked copy of the delivery information, then in the common case I would expect a method signature like:
// Please use better naming than this example!
Order::verb(Value<UnlockedDeliveryInformation> delivery)


On the other hand, if your concern is reporting (ex: displaying information in a user interface), then all of the information is unlocked, and your real concern here is more about schema design.
In that case, you should probably be looking into what we've learned about creating forwards and backwards compatible message schema.  Versioning XML Vocabularies (David Orchard, 2003) is a decent starting point.
I would guess that you'll still want to keep order information distinct from delivery information
{
  "order": {},
  "delivery": {}
}

But it isn't too hard to imagine circumstances where a different design has better trade offs (aka: "it depends").

So afterall it's generally better to make rest/g-rpc queries to particular (micro)services in order to obtain additional information rather than depend on broker events? That'd mean data is fresh and as you said will keep only properties that can be updated in this service

Trade offs.  Synchronous communication may get you fresh data, but it also costs you latency and you introduce a bunch of failure modes that you must address.  You also need to think about where the logical boundaries of the services belong.  Udi Dahan has some interesting discussions on this latter point.
